# Assigning a selector crashes on iPod touch 2nd generation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipod-touch, exc-bad-access

*Update: problem magically disappeared, see comment*

I have a function which works fine on an iPhone 3G, iPhone 3Gs and simulator but crashes on an iPod touch 2nd generation.

```
- (id) initWithDelegate:(id) delegate
   data:(NSData *) data
                     finishSelector:(SEL)finishSelector{
 if(self = [super init]){
  _delegate = delegate;
  _finishSelector = finishSelector; // crashes
```

When it reaches the last line it crashes with “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. When I put a breakpoint on that line and hover over finishSelector, I see this:

[image]

When I hover over _finishSelector I see this:
[image]

When I try "Print Description", the console returns:

> Printing description of finishSelector:
>   The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
>   GDB has restored the context to what it was before the call.

The function is called like so:

```
 _teachersWordPlayer = [[SimplifiedPlayer alloc] initWithDelegate:self 
data:_audioFileService.responce
finishSelector:@selector(teachersAudioPlayerDidPlay:)];
```

Part of the header file looks like this:

```
@interface SimplifiedPlayer : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
  AVAudioPlayer *_soundPlayer;
  id _delegate;
  SEL _finishSelector;
}
- (id) initWithDelegate:(id) delegate
   data:(NSData *) data
   finishSelector:(SEL)finishSelector;
```

I also tried to enable NSZombie, but it doesn't provide any more details about the crash (I don't expect it to, because I never released _finishedSelector afaik).

Can anyone tell me what's going on, how to fix this and/or how to find out what's going on?

Comment: You have a crash at a simple data assign operator, it must be something wrong with SELF object, not _finishSelector. I can't see any weakness in the code, it's pretty simple.. Any other threads? Could something corrupt the memory: release call, data assigns?

Comment: I'm very new to threading. Just before the crashing operation, there are 6 threads. Thread 2 is at kevent, thread 3 at mach_msg_trap, 4 at mach_msg_trap, 5 at select$DARWIN_EXTSN, 6 at _workq_kernreturn. I have no idea what these threads are doing, but it doesn't look like anything related to my code.

Comment: I think this is the first time this object is created, so I don't think it's been released yet. But I'm not sure. How would I go about finding out?

Comment: I have two applications (student and teacher), with some common files. This application (student) included the teacher  application and they both included their own copy of Three20. 
After I wrote this post we changed it so that both apps include the same copy and a newer version of Three20. That introduced lots of "random" compiler warnings and a new crash on whatever first Three20 method that was called.
Then I noticed that only happened in the student app. In stead of including the teacher project, I directly include the files.
It made the warnings, new crash and this crash go away. Presto